# Is there a way to force circular integer overflow in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to convert some Java code to Excel and the required hashcode function generates an overflow error, instead of wrapping to the negative

```
Function FnGetStringHashCode(ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim result, i
    FnGetStringHashCode = 17
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        Dim c, a
        c = Mid(str, i, 1)
        a = AscW(c)
        FnGetStringHashCode = 31 * FnGetStringHashCode + a
    Next i
End Function
```

Is there a way of doing this in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there is no built-in way to do this, the computation is simple:

```
Public Function coerceLongToInt(toCoerce As Long) As Integer
    Const MIN_INT As Long = -32768
    Const MAX_INT As Long = 32767
    Const NUM_INTS As Long = MAX_INT - MIN_INT + 1

    Dim remainder As Long
    remainder = toCoerce Mod NUM_INTS

    If remainder > MAX_INT Then
        coerceLongToInt = remainder - NUM_INTS
    ElseIf remainder < MIN_INT Then
        coerceLongToInt = remainder + NUM_INTS
    Else
        coerceLongToInt = remainder
    End If
End Function
```

This is the behavior you want, right?

```
?coerceLongToInt(-32769)
 32767 
?coerceLongToInt(-32768)
-32768 
?coerceLongToInt(-1)
-1 
?coerceLongToInt(0)
 0 
?coerceLongToInt(1)
 1 
?coerceLongToInt(32767)
 32767 
?coerceLongToInt(32768)
-32768
```

You would use it like this:

```
Function FnGetStringHashCode(ByVal str As String) As Integer
    Dim result, i
    FnGetStringHashCode = 17
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        Dim c, a
        c = Mid(str, i, 1)
        a = AscW(c)
        FnGetStringHashCode = coerceLongToInt(31 * CLng(FnGetStringHashCode) + a)
    Next i
End Function
```

You need the 'CLng' call in there to prevent VBA from raising an overflow error when it computes the intermediate value (31 * [some integer >= 1058]).

Comment: thanks, I did end up having to change it from integers and longs to longs and decimals for my application (I didn't realise that was necessary when I asked the question) but otherwise spot on

Answer (score 0):

I have modified a little the script of ours. The main difference is returning type of your function. Now it returns **Variant**. As decimal is a subset of Variant, and it can store bigger numbers than long I think it is a good solution ([see VBA data types](http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/601315-vba-data-types)) - I do not know is it possible to explicitly return Decimal. Here is the script

```
Function FnGetStringHashCode(ByVal str As String) As Variant

    Dim tmp As Variant, c As String, a As Integer, i As Integer

    tmp = 17

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        c = Mid$(str, i, 1)
        a = AscW(c)
        tmp = 31 * tmp + a
    Next i
    FnGetStringHashCode = tmp
End Function
```

And a little test routine

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print CStr(FnGetStringHashCode("dawdaedae"))
End Sub
```

Comment: I could not find how to define a var of type Decimal, only that the casting function is **CDec()**.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MPękalski, but I actually still want the value to overflow. This is the correct answer if I want to store a number bigger than `long`

Comment: Sorry, I must have been in a hurry, I have not read that you wanted the value to be negative on overflow. As for now I do not know how to do it if not by adding a condition to my script that if it is bigger than Long then return a negative and so on...